# How to set a field of a user, a default for another field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that I want connected to all models. I did that using foreinkeys. I don't want the user to fill out that field by himself, that's because the user model has that field too therefore I want the data to be filled in automatically using request.user.that_field. I am using CreateView for creating model instances, i am pretty sure there is a way to do what I want but am not clear about what it is. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Simply don't have the field in your model since it already exists in the related model (Why store duplicate data? Then you would have to deal with updating both tables together etc. Not worth it)

Comment: Mate, (1) I am doing that for specific reasons. (2) the user isnt a foreinkey in that model. What I want is that I want to set the data from the request data..

Comment: You need to override form_valid in your view class. (form_valid is the method that saves the form)

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, MUCH THANKS!